# How can I replace a specific key's value in an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I have a an array that has 3 values. After the user pushes the submit button I want it to replace the the value of a key that I specify with another value.

If I have an array with the values `(0 => A, 1 => B, 2 => C)`, and the function is run, the resulting array should be `(0 => A, 1 => X, 2 => C)`, if for example the parameter for the function tells it to the replace the 2nd spot in the array with a new value.

How can I replace a specific key's value in an array in php?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you know the key, you can do:

```
$array[$key] = $newVal;
```

If you don't, you can do:

```
$pos = array_search($valToReplace, $array);
if ($pos !== FALSE)
{
   $array[$pos] = $newVal;
}
```

Note that if $valToReplace is found in $array more than once, the first matching key is returned. More about [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to have an inline solution you can use [array_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) or [array_replay_recrusive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php) depending on which suits you best.

```
$replaced_arr = array_replace([
        'key' => 'old_value',
        0 => 'another_untouched_value'
    ],[
        'key' => 'new_value'
    ]);
```

It would be best if your array is key/value pair